# URL routing in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Homework done:

[The Node Beginner Book](http://www.nodebeginner.org)

[How do I get started with Node.js [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js)

[Structuring handlers in Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143762/routing-requests-and-structuring-response-handlers-in-node)

Backstory: I wanted to try and write my own framework but I'm running into some troubles, most likely due to not understanding it fully.

What I want to achieve is a syntax that looks like this:

```
var app = require('./app'); //this part is understood and it works in my current code.
app.get('/someUrl', function(){ //do stuff here });
app.post('/someOtherUrl', function(){ //do stuff here });
```

I know of the Express-framework that has this same syntax but reading their source code still eludes me.

This might be a trivial task to achieve but I simply can't produce it, yet.

Trying to `require('./app');` in a file deeper in the application produces a undefined object, so I'm guessing that a server is a singleton object.

So what have I tried?

My current code looks like this, and somehow I feel like this is the way to go, but I can't apparently do it like this.

I'm omitting all the `require();` statements to keep it more readable.

**server.js:**

```
var app = module.exports = {
    preProcess: function onRequest(request, response){
        processor.preRequest(request); //this object adds methods on the request object
        var path = urllib.parse(request.url).pathname;
        router.route(urls, path, request, response);
    },
    createServer: function() {
        console.log("Server start up done.");
        return this.server = http.createServer(this.preProcess);
    }
};

exports.app = app;
```

At the time of writing I'm experimenting with extending this object with a `get()` method.

**index.js:**

```
var app = require('./server');
app.createServer().listen('1337');
```

the `router.route()` bit basically sends the request onward into the application and inside the router.js-file I do some magic and route the request onward to a function that maps (so far) to the /urlThatWasRequested

This is the behavior I'd like to leave behind.
I know this might be a pretty tall order but all my code is easily discardable and I'm not afraid of rewriting the entire codebase as this is my own project.

I hope this is sufficient in explaining my question otherwise, please say what I should add to make this a bit more clear.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your question is, but here's some thoughts:

**1)** You are creating a circular reference here:

```
var app = module.exports = {
    // some other code
}
exports.app = app;
```

You add `app` as a property of `app`. There's no need for the last line.

**2)** You need to hold handlers in `app`. You can try something like this:

```
var app = module.exports = {
    handlers : [],
    route : function(url, fn) {
        this.handlers.push({ url: url, fn: fn });
    },
    preProcess: function onRequest(request, response){
        processor.preRequest(request);
        var path = urllib.parse(request.url).pathname;
        var l = this.handlers.length, handler;
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            handler = this.handlers[i];
            if (handler.url == path)
                return handler.fn(request, response);
        }
        throw new Error('404 - route does not exist!');
    },
    // some other code
}
```

Note that you may alter this line: `if (handler.url == path)` in such a way that `handler.url` is a regular expression and you test `path` against it. Of course you may implement `.get` and `.post` variants, but from my experience it is easier to check whether a request is `GET` or `POST` *inside* the handler. Now you can use the code above like this:

```
app.route('/someUrl', function(req, res){ //do stuff here });
```

The other thing is that the code I've shown you only fires the **first** handler for a given URL it matches. You would probably want to make more complex routes involving many handlers (i.e. middlewares). The architecture would be a bit different in that case, for example:

```
preProcess: function onRequest(request, response){
    var self = this;
    processor.preRequest(request);
    var path = urllib.parse(request.url).pathname;
    var l = self.handlers.length,
        index = 0,
        handler;
    var call_handler = function() {
        var matched_handler;
        while (index < l) {
            handler = self.handlers[index];
            if (handler.url == path) {
                matched_handler = handler;
                break;
            }
            index++;
        }
        if (matched_handler)
             matched_handler.fn(request, response, function() {
                 // Use process.nextTick to make it a bit more scalable.
                 process.nextTick(call_handler);
             });
        else
             throw new Error('404: no route matching URL!');
     };
     call_handler();
},
```

Now inside your route you can use

```
app.route('/someUrl', function(req, res, next){ 
    //do stuff here
    next(); // <--- this will take you to the next handler
});
```

which will take you to another handler (or throw exception if there are no more handlers).

**3)** About these words:

> Trying to require('./app'); in a file deeper in the application produces a undefined 
>   object, so I'm guessing that a server is a singleton object.

It isn't true. `require` always returns the reference to the module object. If you see `undefined`, then you've messed up something else (altered the module itself?).

**Final note:** I hope it helps a bit. Writing your own framework can be a difficult job, especially since there already are excelent frameworks like Express. Good luck though!

**EDIT**

Implementing `.get` and `.set` methods is actually not difficult. You just need to alter `route` function like this:

```
route : function(url, fn, type) {
    this.handlers.push({ url: url, fn: fn, type: type });
},
get : function(url, fn) {
    this.route(url, fn, 'GET');
},
post : function(url, fn) {
    this.route(url, fn, 'POST');
},
```

and then in routing algorithm you check whether `type` property is defined. If it is not then use that route (`undefined` type means: always route). Otherwise additionally check if a request's method matches type. And you're done!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :) My question was "How to produce a .get(), .post() syntax". I might have to alter the question. The reason why I would like to refrain from checking for get/post in the function itself is just because of preference in this project. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! :) Also I have a handlers-file where I add a lot of handlers that map to functions by the same name I'm not sure if that was made clear.

Comment: this might be a totally moronic question but the handlers property isnt instatiated, it's just undefined.

Comment: @limelights I've defined it at the begining of **2)** section: `var app = module.exports = { handlers : [],`.

Comment: yeah, i know, but it still turns up as undefined when i run it and i cant for the love of god see why it does it.

Comment: @limelights Hmm, maybe you should post the code you've written and we look at it?? Remember that `this` always refers to the **holder** of a function (`app` in my case). Also you may trying converting the code into classical `function()` style, instantiate it and export it.

Comment: I'll try to the export but otherwise im using your exact code for testing purposes. :)

Comment: i got it to work! I did learn a lot as well! :) Thanks for the excellent answer! :)